# Tomcat through Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver

I'd like to know if is a good decision to **configure tomcat through port 80** (in apache with virtual-hosts ).

I need to setup a tomcat service in the same server I have apache, plus I need to use **Tomcat through port 80**.

Is this right? or is best to use them in separated servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's OK. But sometimes tomcat is deployed with Apache. The Apache is a front-end server to balance load. And many tomcats are as back-end servers.